# How to check if a GWT Panel is empty?

Tags: gwt

How to check if a GWT Panel (VerticalPanel, HorizontalPanel, etc.) is empty?

I used this code:

```
if (contactListPanel.getWidget(0) == null) { 
 // stuff
}
```

However, it throws an exception:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
....
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
```

Comment: is contactListPanel null? What sort of exception?

Comment: Its IndexOutOfBoundsException, however I don't see a function in a gwt panel to check the current size of the Panel at least to test if there's something on it.

Comment: that means there is no 0th element; check the size of the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Erm ... `getWidgetCount()` would seem to be what you're looking for.

Comment: Wow, I overlooked that. Thanks.